# How to do a Mysql SELECT statement based on IF condition?

Tags: mysql, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to combine 2 mysql calls into one with and if condition. This is what I currently have:

```
IF
mysql_query("SELECT File FROM DB.ShoePics WHERE Cover='1' AND ShoeID='$ShoeID' LIMIT 1")
Else
mysql_query("SELECT File FROM DB.ShoePics WHERE Cover='0' AND ShoeID='$ShoeID' LIMIT 1")
```

I guess it would look something similar to this but I know its incorrect:

```
mysql_query("SELECT File FROM DB.ShoePics WHERE IF(Cover='1')ELSE(Cover='0') AND ShoeID='$ShoeID' LIMIT 1")
```

Can someone show me how? thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Use the row for "Cover = 1" if available, otherwise the row for "Cover = 0"?

Comment: You did not provide any condition for using one or the other...

Comment: Sorry.. Frank what you said is what I am trying to accomplish. Select if cover=1 is available if not then any other would do.

Answer (score 0):

make your query like

```
SELECT File FROM DB.ShoePics WHERE (Cover='1' OR Cover='0') AND ShoeID='$ShoeID' LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT File 
FROM DB.ShoePics 
WHERE  
    CASE WHEN CONDITION=1 THEN Cover='1' ELSE Cover='0' END
    AND ShoeID='$ShoeID' LIMIT 1"
```

Comment: This unfortunely didn't work. It gave me the first record it found and not the row with cover=1... I'm basically trying to get the picture of the shoe that the user wants to set as a cover. And if user hasn't set the cover then to select the first pic available.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query("SELECT File FROM DB.ShoePics WHERE (Cover='1' AND ShoeID='$ShoeID' LIMIT 1") OR (Cover='0' AND ShoeID='$ShoeID' LIMIT 1")